# Pretending SD card by other device or sharing one SD card by two devices

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, sd-card, spi

I'm looking for a hint to get started with my project.

I have one device which is reading data from SD card. I'm unable to control it remotelly in any way - I can "control" this device only by saving new data on this SD card. I need to do it manually - so if I want to change some data on 10 devices, I need to take out 10 sd card, send new data, and put it back to devices.

1) I wonder if I can pretend SD card using arduino or raspbery.
Instead of reading data from SD card, this device would read data directly from arduino. Arduino I can control easly.

2) Second solution is to share one SD card by two devices. Arduino/RaspberryPi/Android device will be sending data to SD card and the other device will be reading data.

But I want to change data in each 10-15 seconds so It can be problematic for sharing one SD card.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Is it even possible? 
EDIT:
Maybe I didn't mention that clear, but I can't change the reading device, I can't install anything there. It's blackbox device which is only reading data from SD card.

Comment: Do you know how the reading device accesses the SD card.  If it uses the SPI interface you might be able to have the RPi emulate the SPI SD card protocol a appear as an SD card to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Dropbox Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync) to do one way syncing of all my devices. Simply change a single file or folder in Dropbox and then my devices fetch all changes and write to their SD card.

This though has some challenges and took me some time to get working. Mainly because the Sync API is not designed to behave as Dropbox does on a PC, automatically downloading files. Rather, it is able to tell which files have changed and then lazily fetch them when requested. As this might be sufficient for your use case, I needed offline access to the files and had to jump a few hoops to make it actually download files to SD before the user actually request them.

If you only need relatively simple data or small files, I would suggest [parse.com](http://parse.com). Note that I have no experience with this system yet but it looks very promising.

**Edit:**

Now understanding that the above is not possible for you, then sharing SD between devices should be OK, I think. You could create a simple empty file such as .lock while writing to SD and delete it immediately after. This way, whenever one of the units try to read the data, if they see the .lock file, they know that they should wait a bit before reading/writing again. Could be a simple solution to avoid corrupting the data.

Comment: Maybe I didn't mention that clear, but I can't change the reading device, I can't install anything there. It's blackbox device which is only reading data from SD card.

Comment: I see, was just in the mindset of android :) then I do not have any clever ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options: either emulate an SD card or use a real SD card and switch it between your Arduino and the reading device.

To emulate an SD card you'd need to use an FPGA and write quite lot of VHDL/Verilog code. You can't do that by microcontroller software because of the high clock rates involved (the host may ask data from you at several megabps's speed).

Additionally, even if you would be able to do it, there's a fair chance that you still would have to "disconnect" the SD card from the reader, at least for a little while, when you are making changes - otherwise the reader would have no idea that you have changed the card's contents: it might not read the new files or might even overwrite them.